# Terraform for_each for maps inside map

Tags: foreach, terraform

I am wondering if it would be possible to iterate over a structure like this using a combination of for_each/for

```
module "network" {
  source    = "../../"
  role                = "test"
  resource_group_name = xyz
  location            = "centralus"
  environment         = "test-1"
  tags = {
    role = "unit-test"
  }
  subnets = {
    subnet-1 = {
      name              = "subnet-a"
      cidr              = "10.0.1.0/24",
      nsg = {
        httpallowinbound = {
          name = "junk"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can do a for_each on the outer structure to obtain values and assign them to respective fields but cannot do for the nested structure above. Appreciate any feed back so far. What I have so far:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "this" {
  for_each             = var.subnets
  name                 = lookup(each.value, "name")
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.this.name
  address_prefix       = lookup(each.value, "cidr"
}
```

Out of ideas for this piece

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "this" {
   Map NSGs to Subnets 
}
```

----------------------Update-1---------------------------------------------

Based on finding so far, the flatten function is supposed to provide this mechanism as described [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html)

However, I am unable to get the example working as well:

Main.tf

```
variable "networks" {
  type = map(object({
    cidr_block = string
    subnets = map(object({
      cidr_block = string
    })) # this is missing in the document
  })) # this is missing in the document
}

locals {
  # flatten ensures that this local value is a flat list of objects, rather
  # than a list of lists of objects.
  network_subnets = flatten([
    for network_key, network in var.networks : [
      for subnet_key, subnet in network.subnets : {
        network_key = network_key
        subnet_key  = subnet_key
        #network_id  = aws_vpc.example[network_key].id
        cidr_block  = subnet.cidr_block
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "null_resource" "dynamic_self" {
  for_each = {
    for subnet in local.network_subnets : "${subnet.network_key}.${subnet.subnet_key}" => subnet
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${local.network_subnets}"
  }
}
```

*.tfvars

```
networks = {
    network-1 = {
      cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
      subnets = {
        subnet-1 = {
          cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/24"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This fails with error: *Error: Invalid template interpolation value: Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.*

--------------------Update-2-----------------------------------------

Looks like flatten is the right function for this use case and I have moved quite farther down the lane but the last stage is still not working. What I have now:

**Values.tfvars**

```
  subnets = {
    inbound-subnet = {
      name              = "subnet-a"
      cidr              = "10.0.1.0/24",
      nsgs = {
        nsg1 = {
            httpallowinbound = {
              name                       = "httpallow"
              priority                   = 100
              direction                  = "Inbound"
              access                     = "Allow"
              protocol                   = "Tcp"
              source_port_range          = "*"
              destination_port_range     = "*"
              source_address_prefix      = "*"
              destination_address_prefix = "*"
            },
            httpdenyinbound = {
              name                       = "httpdeny"
              priority                   = 101
              direction                  = "Inbound"
              access                     = "Deny"
              protocol                   = "Tcp"
              source_port_range          = "*"
              destination_port_range     = "*"
              source_address_prefix      = "*"
              destination_address_prefix = "*"
           },
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**locals**

```
nsgs = flatten([
    for subnets_name, subnets_values in var.subnets : [
      for nsg_name, nsg_values in subnets_values.nsgs : [
        for rule_name, rule_values in nsg_values: {
          nsg_name                   = nsg_name
          rule                       = rule_name
          name                       = rule_values.name
          priority                   = rule_values.priority
          direction                  = rule_values.direction
          access                     = rule_values.access
          protocol                   = rule_values.protocol
          source_port_range          = rule_values.source_port_range
          destination_port_range     = rule_values.destination_port_range
          source_address_prefix      = rule_values.source_address_prefix
          destination_address_prefix = rule_values.destination_address_prefix
       }
      ]
    ]
  ])
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "this" {
  for_each             = var.subnets
  name                 = lookup(each.value, "name")
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.this.name
  address_prefix       = lookup(each.value, "cidr")
}


resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "this" {
  for_each = {
      for sg in local.nsg_name:
        "${sg.nsg_name}" => sg
  }
  name                 = each.value.nsg_name
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
}


resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "this" {
  for_each = {
      for sg in local.nsgs:
        //"${sg.rule}.${sg.name}" => sg
        sg.nsg_name => sg...
  }
  name                        = each.value.name
  priority                    = each.value.priority
  direction                   = each.value.direction
  access                      = each.value.access
  protocol                    = each.value.protocol
  source_port_range           = each.value.source_port_range
  destination_port_range      = each.value.destination_port_range
  source_address_prefix       = each.value.source_address_prefix
  destination_address_prefix  = each.value.destination_address_prefix
  resource_group_name         = var.resource_group_name
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.this[tostring(each.key)]
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

Error: Incorrect attribute value type

on ../../vnet.tf line 55, in resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "this":
  55:   network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.this[tostring(each.value.nsg_name)]
    |----------------

```
| azurerm_network_security_group.this is object with 1 attribute "nsg1"
| each.value.nsg_name is "nsg1"
```

Inappropriate value for attribute "network_security_group_name": string
required.

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../../vnet.tf line 55, in resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "this":
  55:   network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.this[tostring(each.value.nsg_name)]
    |----------------
    | azurerm_network_security_group.this is object with 1 attribute "nsg1"
    | each.value.nsg_name is "nsg1"
```

I am sure I am missing something tiny because it looks it is doable. Any pointers would really help

Comment: Last time I heard, nested iterators were not yet implemented in Terraform DSL.

Comment: I found this: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html and seems like this is the exact case I have but unable to get it working. WIP

Comment: The `flatten` function is indeed the important building-block here. Could you edit your question to share what you've tried with `flatten` so far and what result you saw, and then maybe someone can help you figure out the remaining details?

Comment: Unfortunately the depicted example in the document itself is not working. Let me add that here.